# Can't toggle <ul> with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Any ideas why I can't toggle my unordered list?

Am I supposed to target the `li` items instead of the whole menu class?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="cae.js"></script>

    <title>
        Code Academy Examples
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>

    <button type="submit" class="btn" title="show/hide">Click Here</button>
</body>
</html>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( ".btn" ).click( function(){

        $( ".menu" ).toggle();

    });

});
```

Comment: If your page by chance refreshing / flickering?

Comment: Nope, it loads everything just fine why do you ask?

Comment: Have you [included the jQuery library](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/)?

Comment: Nevermind - you forgot to include jQuery

Comment: Such as this?

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Below may work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( ".btn" ).click( function(){

        $( ".menu li" ).toggle();

    });

});
```

At the same time, you must include JQuery

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Such a silly mistake.. thanks for the help!

I used

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And it is working correctly.